# Android Studio: Creating landscape layouts

Tags: android, layout, android-studio, android-resources

Until recently I used Eclipse, and in Eclipse I simply created a folder /res/layout-landscape and put alternate landscape layouts inside.

However, it seem in Android Studio 1.1.0, I can't do it that way. How do I create the folder for alternate landscape layouts?

Comment: This is a good question. It is not clear from any tutorials how to do this in the latest Android studio. As it is such a common problem (you will nearly always need a landscape view) I am surprised it is not more clearly documented for Android studio. There are plenty of guides for eclipse that are now out of date. Thanks for your question.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can actually use `layout-land` in Android Studio as well it will show up in your `res` directory like so:

[image: layout-land]

If it doesn't show up make sure to have your project scope set to `Project` and not `Android`.

[image: Project Scope]

If you still don't see one you can create one by right clicking on the res directory and selecting `New -> Android resource directory` and filling out the prompt below.

[image: New directory]

Also, once it's been created, you can easily switch from portrait to landscape in the layout preview via the orientation button found on the toolbar above the layout preview. It is pictured below:

[image: Orientation Toggle]

Comment: That is the exact answer. I coudn't see my layout-land folder because scope was et to "Android" instead of "Project". In this case Android studio will show the landscape version like a subitem of the normal layout. Tx. Pretty confusing, if one comes from Eclipse.

Comment: In my Android studio layout-land is NEVER created and I have to add it manually like you have shown. It is extremely weird and just pure luck I found your answer or I would never have been able to make a landscape layout. Really screwed up I think from the point of view of Android studio - people aren't psychic.

Comment: as @Mark Channer has said, Orientation should be selected and not UI Mode.

Answer (score 45):

You can also use option given in below image.

[image]

I hope you have understood.

Answer (score 27):

The accepted answer is actually seriously outdated. In Android Studio 3.x.x, there is no need to create an extra layout **folder** (I am not sure this was necessary back then anyway).

There is also no need to change the project scope from Android to Project as the accepted answer tells you to.

There is also no need to edit any UI attributes and modes as the accepted answer says.

There are just 2 steps:

1) Open your base UI layout in **DESIGN** mode so that you see the actual GUI, such as buttons, icons etc. (do NOT open it as text, in the XML code view mode).

2) Click the icon marked in the below screenshot and, from the menu, select *Create Landscape Variation* (marked in the screenshot as 'Click 2nd').

Then, the Studio does all the job for you and it works like a charm. No need to add any extra code and no extra folders are created.

Enjoy.

Android Studio 3.1.4:

[image]

Comment: So I literally do not have that "Create Landscape Variation" option. Any idea how to get it back? Or what might have replaced it?

Answer (score 2):

maybe this one is easier

android studio chipmunk :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

MrEngineer13's answer is spot on.

The only thing that I would add is that his screenshot may lead you to believe that you should be selecting 'UI Mode' from the 'Available qualifiers' list.

Just to clarify: after filling out the Directory name and Resource type, select 'Orientation' from Available qualifiers, which will lead you to the screenshot that MrEngineer13 provided.

Answer (score 1):

In the `Project -> app -> src -> main -> res`

Then Create Android resource directory, choose Orientation