# Android App doesn't rotate on normal (non-large) devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, rotation

I'm writing a chat app in which I have two different layouts for normal and large devices, similar to the Telegram app. I have an MainActivity that on non-large devices has only a fragment containing the list of chats in it's layout.xml. On large devices the layout.xml also includes a fragment, where you can write in the chat.

My problem is, that on large devices (e.g. Nexus 9 Virtual Device) the app rotates fine when I rotate the device, the activities are reloaded etc. But on non-large devices the app won't rotate after it is started. I have tried this on  Nexus 5X API22 and Nexus 5 API23 Virtual Devices and on a OnePlus X and a Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge, all with auto-rotate activated. There is nothing in the AndroidManifest or anywhere else in my code, that has any influence on configChanges. I let Android handle them and don't handle them myself.

I can get the app to rotate on non-large devices when I open the app, got to overview or start another app, rotate to landscape and then go back to my app through overview. After doing this, it reacts normally to rotation. This means I can then rotate it around and the layout/activity is reloaded accordingly by Android.

I couldn't find anything on this anywhere, neither on SO, nor through googling. Please help me, if you have any ideas, where this problem could stem from.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815769/android-studio-creating-landscape-layouts

Comment: try this link it may help you.

Comment: this doesn't help, sorry. The layouts are in the correct folders.