# Fixed footer in landscape and portrait mode in Android

Tags: android, footer, android-relativelayout

I would like to have a fixed footer something like this:

[image]

I tried to achieve this using relative layout:

```
   <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/material_grey_850"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Version 1.0 Demo"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_22sdp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:id="@+id/versionText" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/material_grey_850"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Copyright (c) 2017 Aglive Pty Ltd"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:id="@+id/copyrightText"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_below="@id/versionText" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_columnSpan="7"
            android:layout_marginTop="7.0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7.0dp"
            android:id="@+id/relative"
            android:layout_below="@id/copyrightText">
            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="@color/material_grey_850"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Terms of Service"
                android:layout_marginTop="21.5sp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5.5sp"
                android:id="@+id/termsOfService"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15sdp" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="@color/material_grey_850"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Contact Us"
                android:layout_marginTop="21.5sp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:id="@+id/contactUs"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

But the problem here is that whenever the keyboard opens up the footer moves up. For which I tried to add `WindowSoftInputMode =  SoftInput.AdjustPan`. It worked for the keyboard issue but whenever the screen rotates to landscape mode the footer overlaps the other text. Also my relative layout does not come as required.  The relative layout seems to be covering other text.

Comment: than set orientation **`android:screenOrientation="portrait"`** to your activity

Comment: I want may app to have both screen orientation!!

Comment: than use **`Constraint layout`**

Comment: this link may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124046/how-do-i-specify-different-layouts-for-portrait-and-landscape-orientations and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858026/android-alternate-layout-xml-for-landscape-mode and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815769/android-studio-creating-landscape-layouts

Comment: I think that you should put your current layout into `ScrollView`. When the keyboard opens you calculate a distance from top to a view that you want to display(depends on the screen size, keyboard height, etc.). After that, you request the `ScrollView` to scroll to a position depends on the calculated distance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have both modes in the app then you have to make an xml with same name placed in folder layout-land along with the one you have made. With this you will have different layouts for both portrait and landscape and hence this will solve your problem. Hope this helps.

Comment: So does that mean for each and every page where I have a footer, I will have to design it twice for two different modes?

Comment: Yes.. it is relatively easy than it looks. Once one layout is done. Rest are really easy.

Answer (score 0):

Adding,

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

into your `<activity>` node in `manifest.xml` will do the trick.

now, you can listen configuration changes into an `override` method `onConfigurationChanged` in your activity.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  // Perform any action here... resetting the layout or.. values or smoething
}
```

Comment: What should I do in this method? My footer overlaps the content in landscape mode what possibly should I do here?

Comment: Adding `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` did not work?

Comment: Simply adding `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize‌​"` did not work. What should i do in onConfigurationChanged?

Comment: Application crashes if i add `setContentView(R.layout.Layout_id)` in `onConfigurationChanged`

Comment: Make sure you are writing that after `super()`. Post an error about the crash if possible!