# Replace Layout in Android in realtime

Tags: android

WHen I make it from horizontal to vertical i would like to change the whole content of the layout into another layout and it doesn't work.

What part am I missing?

Thank you!

I'm new in Android

```
package com.jfdimarzio.myapplication1;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle out)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(out);

        int sdf = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

        if(sdf == 1)
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.layoutff);
        }
        else
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.layoutff);
        }


    }

}


--------------------------------------------


res\layout\activity_main.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="fsdsdf" />
</LinearLayout>


--------------------------------------------


res\layout\layoutff.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
http://tekeye.uk/android/examples/ui/android-portrait-landscape-screens
```

This is the solution in my situation!

Answer (score 1):

The entire activity will be recreated when you change orientation. You set a specific layout file for a particular orientation and the android framework will automatically use the correct one for the particular orientation.

You can find a list of the various qualifiers here (the one you are looking for is layout-land):

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Instructions on how to create a qualified resource are here:

[Android Studio: Creating landscape layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815769/android-studio-creating-landscape-layouts)