# Android Studio emulator screen collapse

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm using the emulator with Android Studio, and I'm experiencing the phenomenon shown in the image below.

[image]

The problem occurs only when the screen is turned sideways.
It does not happen in the default screen.

I don't know how to solve this problem, and I was wondering if you could tell me something that would help me.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this in three ways:

1. disable screen rotation - add this to the manifest XML under the relevant activity
   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
2. If you want to go the long and better route it seems to me that you are using a layout that is not constraint layout, the latter supports rotation better, and when constraint correctly what is shown here should not happen.
3. If all else fails you can use special layout when the screen is in landscape mode, you can read more here:
   [Android Studio: Creating landscape layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815769/android-studio-creating-landscape-layouts)